# Automate IBM ODM RuleApp build from Git using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, build, odm

I need to build the ODM RuleApp as below

1. Decision Service and Java XOM project is in Git
2. Build the RuleApp through Jenkins from Git
3. The created jar file is to be uploaded to Nexus using Jenkins

To achieve the above, I see that there is an option to build project using command line as specified in the IBM ODM knowledge center
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/odm/8.10?topic=command-building-projects-build-line

The option without Maven, says, there are 2 steps

1. Writing configuration file
2. Building projects

My questions:

1. Should I put the configurations(properties) file in Git at the root level of the projects? In other words, if there is a folder called ODM and within this I commit my Decision Service and Java XOM project, then my configuration file should be directly under “ODM”… is it correct?
   The example given for configuration file is as below. I believe these 4 lines are enough to build my RuleApp along with XOM. I have no extension models.

   project = ../HelloWorld/Hello Main Service/
   output = ../HelloWorld/output
   dep = simple dep
   xom-classpath = XOM jars/hello-xom-1.0.0.jar
2. For building the RuleApp, I see the following command
   java -jar Build_Command_Line_executable_archive -config configuration_file

For example: java -jar rules-compiler/rules-compiler.jar -config samples/config-files/CustomRuleModel.properties

I read that… For each deployment configuration that is referenced by the configuration file, the command builds a RuleApp as a stand-alone archive in the specified output folder. The name of this file comes from the RuleApp name specified in the deployment configuration.

a.  Where should I place rules-compiler.jar?

b.  Is Jenkins referring to the .properties (CustomRuleModel.properties) file in Git? Is this not under the root folder?

c.  Where is this output folder created? How can I move the created RuleApp .jar file to Nexus through Jenkins?

d.  Is there any configuration required at Jenkins for building the ODM RuleApp? Any specific configuration for Nexus?

I have no insights into Git and Nexus and looking for some detailed guidance. Kindly help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several remarks : I suggest to use the maven compiler instead of the rule compiler command as it is simpler to use.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/odm/8.10?topic=SSQP76_8.10.x/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/build_topics/con_buildcmd_prep_env.html

Regarding your questions, if you use that maven plugin :

- a) plugin should be installed in your maven repo
- b) can you precise the question ?
- c) output folder is in target
- d) you can deploy the generated ruleset using the Rule Execution Server REST API (using a curl)

Best
Emmanuel